# Order of tags re-arranged on revision history

Tags: support, tags, edits

Here, I only changed [popups](/questions/tagged/popups) to [popup](/questions/tagged/popup) ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2469346/revisions)):

[image]

What causes this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tags are sorted (automagically) by popularity when you edit a question or change tags on a question. That behavior was introduced a way back.

The order in this case is
[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) (436,915 questions) > [popup](/questions/tagged/popup) (4,864 questions) > [animated](/questions/tagged/animated) (233 questions).

The last change on Tags of this question was back in 2010 when the Tag [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) was added, but there was no automatic reordering ([animated](/questions/tagged/animated), [popups](/questions/tagged/popups), [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery))

Comment: I suspected that was the case but was not sure.